# Setting specific R version for Travis build

Tags: r, travis-ci, devtools

I'm maintaining a branch of my package that is specific for R3.4, as this is required by compatibility with some functions used by my collaborators.

I want to make the package compatible with Travis CI, however, as a newbie, struggle to set up the version correctly. In my .travis.yml, I have the following line:

```
env:
  global:
    - R_VERSION="3.4"
```

However, my build fails:

```
ERROR: this R is version 3.6.1, package 'XXX' requires R == 3.4
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/#environment-variables), you want to set it like `TRAVIS_R_VERSION=3.2.4`